# Firebase.Database.FirebaseException loading data

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I can't figure it out.

I'm trying to load data from my Firebase database into a Xamarin Android app and I'm always getting this type of error.

[image]

This is the stack call.

```
0xC in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:157,13  C#
0x6 in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1021,49  C#
0xC in Android.App.SyncContext. at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:36,19 C#
0xE in Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36,6 C#
0x8 in Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-30/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:84,4 C#
0x8 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:22,5  C#
```

This is how I get those data:

```
public async Task<List<Elementi>> SelectAll()
    {

        return (await firebase
          .Child("Test")
          .OnceAsync<ElementiDiRete>()).Select(elemento => new Elementi
          {
              Posizione = elemento.Object.Posizione,
              Comune = elemento.Object.Comune,
              Nome = elemento.Object.Nome,
              TipoElemento = elemento.Object.TipoElemento,
              idElemento = elemento.Object.idElemento,
              Area = elemento.Object.Area,
              Appartenenza = elemento.Object.Appartenenza,
              Coordinate = elemento.Object.Coordinate
    }).ToList();
    }
```

And this is Elementi.cs class:

```
    public class Elementi
{ 
    public int idElemento { get; set; }
    public string TipoElemento { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Comune { get; set; }
    public string POP { get; set; }
    public string Posizione { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public int Coordinate { get; set; }
    public string Appartenenza { get; set; }

}
```

Also I noticed that if I use LimitToLast(10), obviously with OrderbyKey() the application seems to work. I think there are some problems in deserialization. The db was originally created in DB Browser for SQLLite, then exported as JSON and uploaded to my Firebase console.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I also tried several times to export the table as CSV and then convert it to JSON using online tools, but the result is the same.

Comment: anybody can help...

Comment: No ways????????